# Automatically email deleted rows using googlescript

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a google sheet as mentioned below.

```
Col1         Col2        Col3 
ABC          DEF         Test
ABC          DEF         Pending
ABC          DEF         Final
ABC          DEF         Final
ABC          DEF         Reject
ABC          DEF         Test
```

I am using below mentioned code to delete the rows, where `Col3` contains value like 'Final' or 'Reject'.

```
function deleteSelectedRows() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=ss.getSheetByName('Test');
  var rg=sh.getDataRange();
  var vA=rg.getValues();
  var d=0;
  for(var i=1;i<vA.length;i++) {
    if(vA[i][2].toString().toLowerCase()=="final" || vA[i][2].toString().toLowerCase()=="reject")  {
      sh.deleteRow(i-d+1)
      d++;
    }
  }
}
```

I want to send the deleted rows details with heading to particular email id, In below mentioned format.

```
Col1      Col2       Col3 
ABC       DEF        Final
ABC       DEF        Final
ABC       DEF        Reject
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope, the following code will help you:

```
function deleteSelectedRows() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh = ss.getSheetByName('Test');
  var rg = sh.getDataRange();
  var vA = rg.getValues();
  var d = 0;
  var report = [vA[0]];
  for(var i = 1; i < vA.length; i++) {
    var key = vA[i][2].toString().toLowerCase();
    if(key == "final" || key == "reject")  {
      sh.deleteRow(i - d + 1);
      d++;
      report.push(vA[i]);
    }
  }
  report = report.map(function(line) {
    return line.join("\t");
  });
  var body = report.join("\n");
  MailApp.sendEmail('abc@gmail.com', 'Deleted Rows', body);
}
```

We keep report array while deleting rows. At the end we join double array to make plain text to send it via [MailApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/mail/mail-app#sendEmail(String,String,String)).

**Additional question:** how to send this as attachment? Yes, it is possible too. CSV or Excel formats need more efforts, but here we can show a very basic example with simple TSV attachment to understand the way. Let's modify the last code line as follows:

```
  var blob = Utilities.newBlob(body, "text/tab-separated-values", '1.tsv');
  MailApp.sendEmail('abc@gmail.com', 'Deleted Rows', "See attachment", {
    attachments: [blob]
  });
```

We have used ready **body** plain text and only packed it with proper mime type.

Comment: can't send attachment in csv or excel??